# Add a List to PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, preferencescreen

My app has a TabHost with various tabs inside. I have added (outside of the TabHost) a button that calls another activity extended from PreferenceActivity to manage the preferences of the app. For the PreferenceActivity I have followed the PreferenceWithHeaders example from API Demos. Now, I want to add a List inside a category of one of the Headers (inside a PreferenceCategory) that shows the name of all the tabs from TabHost.

Is there any way to do it or should I consider using another type of resources like fragments combined with SharedPreferences?

Thanks in advance